# Right floats extend parent width in IE7

Tags: html, css, css-float, internet-explorer-7, centering

Summary: I'm trying to center two elements in IE7.

I cannot modify the order of the elements, but I want the first element to display to the right of the second, so I have floated them right.

I've also marked them `inline-block` (using the IE7 fix) so that `text-align: center` can apply. Unfortunately, this only seems to work if I float the elements in class `.right` *to the left*.

The code is something as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#outer {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
#wrapper { 
   display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;

}
.right { float: right }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="wrapper">

 <div class="right">Right</div>
 <div class="right">Left</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get around this without resorting to javascript that I'm missing?

Comment: Use JavaScript to switch the order of the elements around?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can always resort to that. Edited the question to ask for non-javascript solutions.

Comment: I could name other solutions, such as the one released in 2009 by Microsoft itself, but I'm sure that is not an option, so I'm not gonna nag you about it.

Comment: :) Unfortunately not